# NetBeans IDE Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException while creating java project

Tags: java, ide

I get this error each time I create a java project.

I have tried different versions of JDK and gives the same error note that my IDE is latest update.

Here is the error code.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol starting from ModuleCL@721c5d4e[org.netbeans.modules.java.source.base] with possible defining loaders null and declared parents [ModuleCL@2acc77b3[org.netbeans.api.java], ModuleCL@661b3a59[org.netbeans.libs.javacapi], ModuleCL@2ec50621[org.netbeans.modules.java.lexer], ModuleCL@7698b66a[org.netbeans.modules.editor.mimelookup], ModuleCL@47bc164[org.netbeans.modules.refactoring.api], ModuleCL@2bfed89a[org.netbeans.api.annotations.common], ModuleCL@4384ac5a[org.netbeans.modules.parsing.api], ModuleCL@2d977913[org.netbeans.modules.lexer], org.netbeans.MainImpl$BootClassLoader@34c45dca, ModuleCL@64102b49[org.netbeans.modules.java.platform], ...20 more]
at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.doFindClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:215)
at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:125)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)                      
Caused: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/tools/javac/code/Symbol
at org.netbeans.modules.java.api.common.classpath.ModuleClassPaths$ModuleInfoClassPathImplementation.lambda$getModulesByName$22(ModuleClassPaths.java:1134)
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: No. You are using an old IDE. The current version is 12.4 and supports Java 16. https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb124/nb124.html

Comment: My IDE is 12.4 already and JDK 16 and still get the same error :/

Comment: What is the result of `java -version`?

Comment: java version "16.0.2" 2021-07-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 16.0.2+7-67)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.0.2+7-67, mixed mode, sharing)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was able to solve it in windows by following the steps below:

1. Uninstall Netbeans 12.4. Make sure to delete all the cache files (Drive:\users<user>\AppData\Roaming\Netbeans and Drive:\users<user>\AppData\Local\Netbeans) (Windows)
2. Check your JDK directory (no JRE) and environment variables JAVA_HOME, CLASSPATH and PATH.
3. Install Netbeans 12.4
4. Create new project and check that you select Download and activate nb-javac.